# "SwiftKeychainWrapper.framework code signing failed" while distributing .ipa

Tags: swift, code-signing, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

When I want to distribute my .ipa file, I'm getting "code signing failed" error.

After I updated my Xcode version to 10.0, this problem occured. Is there anyone that had this problem before ?

[image]

The distribution standard log:

```
  code = 330;
        description = "Failed to resolve linkage dependency SwiftKeychainWrapper x86_64 -> @rpath/libswiftUIKit.dylib: Unknown arch x86_64";
        info =             {
        };
        level = WARN;
    },
            {
        code = 306;
        description = "Failed to resolve rpath for SwiftKeychainWrapper: Could not resolve @executable_path for @executable_path/Frameworks from SwiftKeychainWrapper";
        info =             {
        };
        level = WARN;
    },
            {
        code = 0;
        description = "Failed to verify bitcode in SwiftKeychainWrapper.framework/SwiftKeychainWrapper:\nerror: Cannot extract bundle from /var/folders/tm/1dmb5cd92zx5txhhfz_5jbpm0000gn/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.TZW/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/SwiftKeychainWrapper.framework/SwiftKeychainWrapper (i386)\n\n";
        info =             {
        };
        level = ERROR;
        type = "malformed-payload";
    }
);
```

}

The distribution pipeline log:

```
XcodeDistPipeline.dIk/Root/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/SwiftKeychainWrapper.framework: code object is not signed at all
2018-09-22 20:40:14 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1
```

Regards,

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: I solved with this script. : https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13401 @abhi1992

Comment: Alternatively, you can add SwiftKeychainWrapper.framework to only Linked Frameworks and Libraries instead of Embedded Binaries. Also, you should add this script in Build Phases if you are using carthage. $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/SwiftKeychainWrapper.framework